# Twilio handling calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to achive is whenever I receive an text message with certain keywords, I will get a call saying that I have received a text message and press 1 to talk to the person who sent the text message.

I have done it by creating three files, these are below

Twilio.php

This receives the post request on a text message and call me

```
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];

  $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

  try {
    // make call
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
      $caller,                
      $number,                       
      array("url" => "http://somewebsite.net/twilio/twiml.php?phone=$phone&name=$name")  
    );
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error starting phone call: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
```

The next file if twiml.php which handle the call and ask me if I want to speak and press 1 to speak

twiml.php

```
   $nm = $_GET['name'];
   $ph = $_GET['phone'];

   $name  = "Deepak";
   header("content-type: text/xml");
   echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello <?php echo $name ?>.</Say>
    <Gather numDigits="1" action="http://somewebsite.net/twilio/call.php?phone=<?php echo $ph ?>" method="POST">
        <Say>You have a text message, press 1 to speak.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

The third file is called if I press 1 to speak and then it dials that number : below is the code:

Call.php

```
<?php


    if($_REQUEST['Digits'] != '1') {
        header("Location: twiml.php");
        die;
    }

    $ph = $_GET['phone'];

    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Dial>+1 <?php echo $ph ?></Dial>
</Response>
```

I am trying to achieve is to merge these three files into one so I need not to make a Post request and I could handle the whole call in a single file or at least I can merge twiml.php and call.php

Is there a way to combine these?

Comment: I think you can pass a special parameter in the url and on that url check if the parameter is set then execute you code and u can do  that for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could put it all into one file and use the URI that was requested (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) to switch on the code you then run. Or, it might be more interesting to try a small PHP framework that abstracts that away. Something like [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) or [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) might work for you.

I would ask why you need to run this from one file when your feature looks like it works?

Comment: Thank you it worked!!  Yes, this is working. I was trying to eliminate the number of files to manage, so I can make edits in a single file.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the call made is picked by human or voice machine. I can enable the Ifmachine on the first call, but if I need to check the call made from the calls.php , is there a way to check if it goes to the voice mail

Comment: There is no way to do answer machine detection from the `<Dial>` TwiML. You could dial the other end first and perform the detection before calling your own number though. Also, check out our new [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection) which supersedes `ifMachine`.